# What is the maximum bandwidth for running 100000 thread user in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

When i run more number of threads in jmeter, it doesn't give the completed result. so for an eg if i use 
1500 threads
600 Ramp-up time
1 Loop
5gb heap size

which didn't give the completed result. So am having doubt on the bandwidth. So what is the maximum bandwidth should i use for jmeter, if i run the 100000 thread user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is practically impossible to generate 10,00,00 users load from a single JMeter machine, no matter how powerful it is. For such kind of load may be you will need 20 machines or even more. But before we go into that.. you should ask yourself do you really need to test for 10,00,000 users? Is it a business requirement? So I recommend first you decide the realistic requirements for load testing as per the load you expect for application.

Secondly, if you are facing errors, it does not necessarily mean that there is bandwidth issue. These issues could be because of low CPU, memory as well.

I recommend you read answer in following questions that will help you finalize the hardware infrastructure that you need for JMeter load testing.

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15178/for-heavy-jmeter-scripts-what-type-of-servers-should-we-use-to-run-them

Comment: Thank you.. But in my project the client requirement is to login the 50000 user in the login page without getting an error, what will be the maximum system requirement needed?

Comment: Please refer to link to get an idea about hardware requirements. Also accept answer if you found it helpful. thanks.